# Does using headphones to listen to music damage hearing

Tags: medical-science

As seen in the link below headphones can damage hearing. Is this true? Could using noise canceling headphones and having the volume on low help?

http://www.osteopathic.org/osteopathic-health/about-your-health/health-conditions-library/general-health/Pages/headphone-safety.aspx